# Pixi.js Touchmove and Mousemove event target different?

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

Pixi.js Touchmove and Mousemove event target have different targets.  one seems to point to the DisplayObject and the other to the sprite within.  Is there a way to stop propagation?

Thanks!

Comment: What about `currentTarget`?

Comment: Sorry.  Doesn't seem to be available from the PIXI.js library.  It is not a DOM but a 2D Animation Library for Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

PixiInteractionData contains originalEvent where you can prevent immediate propagation. Your function will receive event as argument

```
function (event) {
    event.originalEvent.stopPropagation();
}
```

Also you can check it out in the docs. http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/docs/classes/InteractionData.html